# Include main.rs in other module

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm new to rust. I know, for calling a module in same folder I need to write `mod <module name>` for other folder `mod <module name>{ include!("path to module") }`. I want to include `main.rs` in `extra.rs`, present in same folder, so that I can use `Summary` trait for structure `feed` in `extra.rs`. I get error `recursion limit reached while expanding the macro 'include'`. 
How I can include `main.rs` in `extra.rs`? Is there a better way to write the same code?

error

```
error: recursion limit reached while expanding the macro `include`
 --> src/extra.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     include!("main.rs");
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: consider adding a `#![recursion_limit="256"]` attribute to your crate

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `office_manager`.
```

main.rs

```
mod extra;

pub trait Summary {
    fn print_summry(&self) -> String;
}

pub struct Tweet {
    name: String,
    message: String
}

impl Summary for Tweet {
    fn print_summry(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}: {}",self.name,self.message)
    }
}

fn main() {

    let t = extra::Feed {
        name: String::from("Hanuman"),
        message: String::from("Jai sri Ram")
    };

    println!("{}",t.print_summry());

}
```

extra.rs

```
mod main {
    include!("main.rs");
}


pub struct Feed {
    pub name: String,
    pub message: String
}

impl Summary for Feed {
    fn print_summry(&self) -> String {
        format!("{}: {}",self.name,self.message)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Rust is not C, you **most likely** do not want to use `include!`, just add `use super::*;` at the top of `extra.rs`.

Comment: Actually,  (ab)using `use super::*;` is not good idea either as it brings everything into scope. Just import what you need with `use super::Summary;`. `super` keyword references parent `mod`ule of current one (In this case - `main.rs`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements of parent module can be accessed with help of `super`. Therefore adding `use super::*;` on top or using `super::Summary` both works. But it is better to use `super::Summary` as it don't include everything of `main.rs`.