# How to import a function in main.rs

Tags: rust, import, rust-crates

This may be a stupid question, but I cannot seem to solve this.

I have this kind of file structure:

```
└── src
    ├── another.rs
    ├── some_file.rs
    └── main.rs
```

In the `some_file.rs`, I want to call a function in the `main.rs`. So, I tried to do something like this in the `some_file.rs`:

```
use crate::main


fn some_func() {
   // other code
   
   main::another_func_in_main();
}
```

But the compiler throws an error:

```
use of an undeclared crate or module `main`
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `use crate::another_func_in_main`

Comment: main isn't a module, it's the root of the crate. Try `crate::another_func_in_main();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `main` module, even though you have a `main.rs` file. The stuff you put in the `main.rs` file are considered to be at the *root* of the crate.

So you have two ways to call the function:

##### 1. Directly (w/o use)

```
crate::another_func_in_main();
```

##### 2. By importing it first

```
use crate::another_func_in_main;

// Then in code, no need for a prefix:
another_func_in_main();
```

Comment: Commenting to link https://stackoverflow.com/q/20922091/3650362 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/61244940/3650362 (which points out you can also use `super::` for module paths relative to the current module)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're right, thank you!